# Getting rid of null/empty string values in a C# array

Tags: c#, arrays, null, string

I have a program where an array gets its data using string.Split(char[] delimiter).
(using ';' as delimiter.)

Some of the values, though, are null. I.e. the string has parts where there is no data so it does something like this:

> 1 ;2 ; ; 3;

This leads to my array having null values.

How do I get rid of them?

Comment: You should edit your question to remove null and only state empty strings. string.Split doesn't give null strings, just empty ones.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Try this:

```
yourString.Split(new string[] {";"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: That does not compile. You need to use new char[]{';'} as the first parameter.

Comment: One thing to note is that this will not remove strings consisting of only whitespace.

Comment: Not works as expected. ex: var a = "1" + "," + "" + "," + "2" + "," + " " + "," + "3" + "," + "   " + "," + null + ","+"4";
. a.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
. Console.WriteLine(a.ToString()); will give result of 1,,2, ,3,   ,,4

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Where linq extension method to only return the non-null or empty values.

```
string someString = "1;2;;3;";

IEnumerable<string> myResults = someString.Split(';').Where<string>(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s));
```

Comment: You could possibly insert a .Select(s => s.Trim()) between Split and Where so that whitespace-only strings will get removed as well.

Comment: Note: The Split method never produces null values.

Comment: @TamasCzinege you can use string.IsNullOrWhiteSpaces instead of trim()

Answer (score 2):

```
public static string[] nullLessArray(string[] src)
{
    Array.Sort(src);
    Array.Reverse(src);
    int index = Array.IndexOf(src, null);

    string[] outputArray = new string[index];

    for (int counter = 0; counter < index; counter++)
    {
       outputArray[counter] = src[counter];
    }

    return outputArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace multiple adjacent semicolons with one semicolon before splitting the data.

This would replace two semicolons with one semicolon:

```
datastr = datastr.replace(";;",";");
```

But, if you have more than two semicolons together, regex would be better.

```
datastr = Regex.Replace(datastr, "([;][;]+)", ";");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                words = poly[a].Split(charseparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                foreach (string word in words)
                    {   
                        richTextBox1.Text += (d + 1)+ "  " + word.Trim(',')+ "\r\n";
                        d++;
                    }
```

charseparators is a space