# How to fix extra white-space issue in C# code?

Tags: c#, parsing

I get an error when I get the numbers from a .txt file when I use extra spaces between numbers. Example: 56 (space) (space) (space) 45 (space) (space) 6 (space) (space) (space) (space) (space) 2 789

There is no problem when i use 1 space between numbers. Example: 56 45 6 2 789

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    string[] temp2;
    temp2 = ReadText[i].Split(' ');
    for (int a = 0; a < temp2.Length; a++)
    {
        Value[ValueCount] = float.Parse(temp2[a]);
        ValueCount++;
    }
}
```

I'd expect normally works, but there's something wrong, and I don't get it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting rid of null/empty string values in a C# array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635751/getting-rid-of-null-empty-string-values-in-a-c-sharp-array)

Comment: You'll want to use the `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`, otherwise you will get whitespace entries in your resulting array.

Comment: Check out the second parameter to `string.Split`.  Also, if you use a debugger and look at the result of Split call, you can probably see your problem.  I strongly suggest you use `float.TryParse` and not `float.Parse`.  Finally, please include the error (or, more likely, exception) you are seeing and where it is generated.

Comment: Thanks for all helps, answer has found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `TryParse` to help you

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    string[] temp2;
    temp2 = ReadText[i].Split(' ');
    for (int a = 0; a < temp2.Length; a++)
        if (float.TryParse(temp2[a], out Value[ValueCount]))
            ValueCount++;
}
```

You can also try `StringSplitOptions`

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    string[] temp2;
    temp2 = ReadText[i].Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    for (int a = 0; a < temp2.Length; a++)
        Value[a] = float.Parse(temp2[a]);
}
```

Comment: How does TryParse remove extra spaces?

Comment: @Berkan This should be used in conjunction with the other suggestion.

Comment: @nyssapongjaerdenlarp: The TryParse call will return false for the spurious return values from the split calls. It results in the bad days being ignored. The correct answer is to use the SplitOptions spec (to get rid of the spurious data) and TryParse because it's data from the outside and reasonably likely to be badly formatted at times